# Submitting A form With Jquery, button works but not on 'enter' press

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

I have a bit of jquery that is submitting a email sign up form for me. Everything works fine when the user clicks the button, but when the hit enter it seems the form is trying to submit through the html not through the jquery and you get taken to where the form should post. I have tried using .submit instead of .click but that didnt seem to work

```
$('#email-signup-button').click(function () {
        var email = $('#email-address').val();

        // Check to see if field is blank
        if (email.length < 1) {
            errorLog += ('Please provide an email address.');
            errorCount++;
        }

        // If field is email address, check w/ regex
        if (email.match(emailRegex) == null) {
            if (errorCount == 0) {
                errorLog += ('Email address is invalid.\nPlease verify.');
                errorCount++;
            }
        }

        if (errorCount > 0) {
            alert(errorLog);
            errorCount = 0;
            errorLog = "";
        }
        else {
            $.post("/Home/AddEmail", { emailAddress: email });

            alert('Thank you for signing up!');
            $('#email-address').val("");
            $('#email-signup').hide();
            $('.lb_overlay').hide();
        }

        return false;
    });
}


        <div id="email-signup">
            <h2>
                Content Phrase
            </h2>
            <div class="email-deals-close-button">
            </div>
            <p>
                More Content</p>
            <form action="/Home/AddEmail" class="clearfix" method="post">
            <p class="sign-up">
                <label class="placeholder" for="email-address">
                    some@email.com</label>
                <input type="text" id="email-address" name="email-address" value="" />
            </p>
            <button id="email-signup-button" type="button" class="green-action-button">
                Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is e-mail signup button the submit button (i. e. `type="submit`) for your form?  If not, it should be for this to work.  If you don't want it to be, you can set an event on the window capturing enter and direct it to that button's click event:

```
 $(window).bind('keypress', function(e){
   if ( $( e.originalTarget ).is( ':input' ) && e.keyCode == 13 ) {
     $(#email-signup-button").click();
     e.preventDefault();
   }
 });
```

([code source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/764427/how-to-capture-enter-key-being-pressed-on-pages-containing-multiple-forms/764734#764734))

Also a place to look is to potential  name conflict errors that supposedly cause confusing problems:

> Forms and their child elements should not use input names or ids that conflict with properties of a form, such as submit, length, or method. Name conflicts can cause confusing failures. For a complete list of rules and to check your markup for these problems, see [DOMLint](http://yura.thinkweb2.com/domlint/).

([jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/submit/))

**Ideally find whatever is causing submit not to work and use that.**

Comment: id="email-signup-button" , yes this is my email sign up button

Comment: @Lawrence - but is it `<input type="submit" />`?  Doesn't appear to be, and that would mean `.submit()` wouldn't work as expected.  If you don't want to use a submit button then the window enter fix I provided would work.

Comment: <input type="text" id="email-address" name="email-address" value="" /> is the input they are entering the email in at

Comment: @Lawrence - the button is the concern I have.  You have it set as a regular button, not a submit button.

Comment: Well I thought i didnt need to set it as a <input type="submit" value="Submit" /> i thought i could just use a button tage and call that button in the jquery

Comment: @Lawrence - here's the info on submit from the jQuery documentation itself: "The submit event is sent to an element when the user is attempting to submit a form. It can only be attached to <form> elements. Forms can be submitted either by clicking an explicit `<input type="submit">`, `<input type="image">`, or `<button type="submit">`, or by pressing Enter when certain form elements have focus."

Comment: I apologize for not following but I do now, I think I got it . Thank you for the help, sorry for the dumb questions. Not a seasoned jquery master like you all

Comment: @Lawrence - it's not dumb; glad you are following now.

Answer (score 4):

You should attach to the submit event of the form itself rather than the click of the button.

```
 $("#formid").submit(//your function here);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have your button type set to button. If you want to bind to a submit event, you need your button to be an input and its type to be `type="submit"`.

Answer (score 0):

Prevent the submit from happening:

```
$('#your_form_id').submit(function() {
  return false;
});
```

Comment: the problem is as mentioned by Vincent. he is adding the handle to the button click instead to form submit.

Comment: Ah, okay. That makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind to the form's submit event instead.

```
$('#myForm').submit(function(){ /* do stuff */ });
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
$("form").submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();return false;
});
```